# req.user is blank even after authentication is successful using passportjs with saml

Tags: node.js, passport.js, saml

For my project I need to use authentication using ADFS + SAML.

I have followed the code and details as suggested at

http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-saml and sample code at https://github.com/gbraad/passport-saml-example

During authentication, the authentication is successful, but req.user is always undefined.

When I tried to print the req, using CircularJSON.stringyfy, I can see all the details inside SAMLResponse -> 'body'.

Here is my code snippet

routes.js

```
module.exports = function (app,config,passport) {
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    try {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            console.log(req.session)
            res.send('user authenticated successfully' + req.user.name) // => If I print req using CircularJSON.stringify, I can see all the details.  
           } else {
               //res.send('User not authenticated.')
               res.redirect('/login')
           }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error ' + error);
    }
    
});
app.get('/login',
  passport.authenticate(config.passport.strategy,
    {
      successRedirect: '/',
      failureRedirect: '/login'
    })
);
}
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const path = require('path');
const passport = require('passport');
const morgan = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const errorhandler = require('errorhandler');
const fs = require('fs');

const config = require('./config/config');

console.log('Using configuration', config);

require('./config/passport')(passport, config);

var app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('port', 3000);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://localhost:3000');
  
    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  
    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  
    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  
    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
  });

app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));
app.use(session(
  {
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: 'my_secret',
    cookie: { 
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true
    }
  }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());



require('./config/routes')(app, config, passport);

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
  };
var my_server = https.createServer(options,app)

my_server.listen(3000);
```

passport.js

```
const SamlStrategy = require('passport-saml').Strategy;

module.exports = function (passport, config) {

  passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  });

  passport.use(new SamlStrategy(
    {
      path: config.passport.saml.path,
      entryPoint: config.passport.saml.entryPoint,
      issuer: config.passport.saml.issuer,
    },
    function (profile, done) {
      return done(null,
        {
          id: profile.uid,
          email: profile.email,
          displayName: profile.cn,
          firstName: profile.givenName,
          lastName: profile.sn
        });
    })
  );

};
```

Comment: If you breakpoint or `console.log` in the `passport.serializeUser` function, are the details in the `user` variable?

Comment: In which part of the code does req.user show as undefined?

Comment: @bendataclear  In serializeUser I get all values undefined.. like user 
{ id: undefined,
  email: undefined,
  displayName: undefined,
  firstName: undefined,
  lastName: undefined }

Comment: @Avagantamo I tried where I got  req.isAuthenticated() as true

Comment: But when I tried  console.log(CircularJSON.stringify(req)), I could see SAMLResponse and all details inside body... Not sure what I have missed..

Comment: If you breakpoint or console.log at the passport strategy callback, are you seeing values for the `profile` variable? In the `return done(null, {id: profile.uid.....`?

Comment: Maybe you could test with a custom callback in the `passport.authenticate`, add a function as the second argument, `function(err, user, info)`, as detailed here under "Custom Callback"  http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/ . This might give you more information

Comment: Thanks. I think the issue is because; in profile, there seems to be some namespace example - displayname is coming against http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname. How can we use that for assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

Let me answer my own question, in case someone finds it useful.

The mistake I was making was in passport.use

When I changed it to following, it worked..

```
passport.use(new SamlStrategy(
{
  
  path: config.passport.saml.path,
  entryPoint: config.passport.saml.entryPoint,
  issuer: config.passport.saml.issuer,
  cert: config.passport.saml.cert,
 },
function (profile, done) {
   return done(null,
    {
      id: profile['nameID'],
      email: profile['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name'],
      displayName: profile['http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname'],
      name: profile['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname'],
      lastName: profile['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname']
    });
    
})
```

);